# Calling LDAP from a Stored Procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, ldap

**Background**

I'm trying to migrate from an LDAP identity store to a database backed implementation. There will be a migration period in which it will be necessary to sync any changes to passwords on the database with the LDAP store.

My question is if its possible to make a LDAP modify call from a stored procedure on the Oracle Database. Ideally the stored procedure would be called based off a trigger on the password field.

Comment: Here's where I would start: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/LDAPFromPLSQL9i.php

Comment: Do you know for certain that in both cases (DB authentication store and the LDAP authentication store) the password hashing scheme is the same? If not, you will have an unusable result copied into one side or the other.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL programmatic access to LDAP directories is accomplished with the DBMS_LDAP and DBMS_LDAP_UTIL packages. Complete query, search and object modification is supported.